# When does InputConnection become invalid?

Tags: android

I read the document of InputConnection, the function of finishComposingText() will return false when the input connection is no longer valid.
I am wondering will the inputConnection become null when it's invalid? What does the "invalid input connection" mean?

```
public class MyInputConnection extends InputConnectionWrapper {
private InputConnection conn;
public MyInputConnection(InputConnection target,
    boolean fullEditor) {
    super(target, fullEditor);
    conn = target;
}   

@Override
public boolean finishComposingText() {
    if(conn == null){
        return false;
    }
    return conn.finishComposingText();
}
```

}

Comment: Yeah, I overwrote finishComposingText() in my own InputConnectionWrapper class. The thing I don't understand is why inputConnection will become null?

Comment: At last I figured out, I shouldn't build an instance of MyInputConnection when the argument conn is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer this by myself. So InputConnection becomes null when it's valid. We should avoid create MyInputConnection when the argument `InputConnection target` is null.